# Unable to pass in parameters to SQL Server Stored procedure from Windows batch script

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, batch-file, stored-procedures

I tried searching for the solution here but didn't find one that can solve my problem.  I have following batch script:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=, " %%a in ('\path\batch_output.txt') do (
echo %%a, %%b, %%c
sqlcmd -S server -E  -i path\spu_update_src_trg_ref.sql -v SourceName= %%a Instancname= %%b exitcode= %%c
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
)
```

Inside spu_update_src_trg_ref.sql I have below code:

```
use dbname
go
EXEC dbo.spu_update_src_trg_ref $(SourceName), $(Instancname), $(exitcode)
```

I am running the below batch script via a job scheduler so unable to see the direct error in the cmd. But my job is getting failed and the stored proc is also not getting executed. If need, stored proc is as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spu_update_src_trg_ref
@SourceName VARCHAR(100),
@Instancname VARCHAR(100),
@exitcode INT
AS 
BEGIN 
IF @exitcode=0 
BEGIN 
UPDATE dbo.t_ctrm_ref_src_trg SET LoadStatus='Completed' WHERE SourceTableName=@SourceName;
UPDATE dbo.t_ctrm_instance_status SET InstanceStatus='Completed' WHERE InstanceName=@Instancname;
END 
END
```

Its a simple sp that updates two tables, but I am unable to pass the input parameters from batch script. Please advice.

**Update:**

Thanks everyone for the help. I just removed some spaces and quotes('') from '\path\batch_output.txt' and it worked just fine.  Appreciate all your help

Comment: You could use the "output file" (`-o`) parameter for `sqlcmd` to capture the output of the command to a log file; this should allow you to capture error messages raised from the script executed by `sqlcmd`.

Comment: tried that. nothing coming in output file as well.

Comment: try in batch file`sqlcmd -S server -E  -i path\spu_update_src_trg_ref.sql -v SourceName="%%a" Instancname="%%b" exitcode="%%c"` and in sql script `EXEC dbo.spu_update_src_trg_ref N'$(SourceName)', N'$(Instancname)', N'$(exitcode)'`

Comment: Get read of `GO` in `spu_update_src_trg_ref.sql` script.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Make an effort to sort out the `-o` parameter otherwise you won't be able to troubleshoot in future.

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors in your sqlcmd command. Remove the spaces between the var name, the equal sign, and the value in the "-v" portion.